# How to add column to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to add one column to the array created from `recfromcsv`. In this case it's an array: `[210,8]` (rows, cols).

I want to add a ninth column. Empty or with zeroes doesn't matter.

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
from numpy import recfromcsv
import numpy as np
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
 print("testing")
 my_data = recfromcsv('LIAB.ST.csv', delimiter='\t')
 array_size = my_data.size
 #my_data = np.append(my_data[:array_size],my_data[9:],0)

 new_col = np.sum(x,1).reshape((x.shape[0],1))
 np.append(x,new_col,1)
```

Comment: And what doesn't work about this?

Comment: The thing that is not working is that it doesn't give me the correct dimensions no matter what version I try.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I think that your problem is that you are expecting `np.append` to add the column in-place, but what it does, because of how numpy data is stored, is create a copy of the joined arrays

```
Returns
-------
append : ndarray
    A copy of `arr` with `values` appended to `axis`.  Note that `append`
    does not occur in-place: a new array is allocated and filled.  If
    `axis` is None, `out` is a flattened array.
```

so you need to save the output `all_data = np.append(...)`:

```
my_data = np.random.random((210,8)) #recfromcsv('LIAB.ST.csv', delimiter='\t')
new_col = my_data.sum(1)[...,None] # None keeps (n, 1) shape
new_col.shape
#(210,1)
all_data = np.append(my_data, new_col, 1)
all_data.shape
#(210,9)
```

Alternative ways:

```
all_data = np.hstack((my_data, new_col))
#or
all_data = np.concatenate((my_data, new_col), 1)
```

I believe that the only difference between these three functions (as well as `np.vstack`) are their default behaviors for when `axis` is unspecified:

- `concatenate` assumes `axis = 0`
- `hstack` assumes `axis = 1` unless inputs are 1d, then `axis = 0`
- `vstack` assumes `axis = 0` after adding an axis if inputs are 1d
- `append` flattens array

---

Based on your comment, and looking more closely at your example code, I now believe that what you are probably looking to do is add a *field* to a [*record array*](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Recarray).  You imported both `genfromtxt` which returns a [*structured array*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) and `recfromcsv` which returns the subtly different [*record array* (`recarray`)](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Recarray).  You used the `recfromcsv` so right now `my_data` is actually a `recarray`, which means that most likely `my_data.shape = (210,)` since recarrays are 1d arrays of records, where each record is a tuple with the given dtype.

So you could try this:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.recfunctions import append_fields
x = np.random.random(10)
y = np.random.random(10)
z = np.random.random(10)
data = np.array( list(zip(x,y,z)), dtype=[('x',float),('y',float),('z',float)])
data = np.recarray(data.shape, data.dtype, buf=data)
data.shape
#(10,)
tot = data['x'] + data['y'] + data['z'] # sum(axis=1) won't work on recarray
tot.shape
#(10,)
all_data = append_fields(data, 'total', tot, usemask=False)
all_data
#array([(0.4374783740738456 , 0.04307289878861764, 0.021176067323686598, 0.5017273401861498),
#       (0.07622262416466963, 0.3962146058689695 , 0.27912715826653534 , 0.7515643883001745),
#       (0.30878532523061153, 0.8553768789387086 , 0.9577415585116588  , 2.121903762680979 ),
#       (0.5288343561208022 , 0.17048864443625933, 0.07915689716226904 , 0.7784798977193306),
#       (0.8804269791375121 , 0.45517504750917714, 0.1601389248542675  , 1.4957409515009568),
#       (0.9556552723429782 , 0.8884504475901043 , 0.6412854758843308  , 2.4853911958174133),
#       (0.0227638618687922 , 0.9295332854783015 , 0.3234597575660103  , 1.275756904913104 ),
#       (0.684075052174589  , 0.6654774682866273 , 0.5246593820025259  , 1.8742119024637423),
#       (0.9841793718333871 , 0.5813955915551511 , 0.39577520705133684 , 1.961350170439875 ),
#       (0.9889343795296571 , 0.22830104497714432, 0.20011292764078448 , 1.4173483521475858)], 
#      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<f8'), ('total', '<f8')])
all_data.shape
#(10,)
all_data.dtype.names
#('x', 'y', 'z', 'total')
```

Comment: Getting File "d:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 18, in _sum
    out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Comment: @user2130951 What is the `dtype` of your array? `my_data.dtype`

Comment: @user2130951 Are you sure you don't want to add a _field_?

Answer (score 19):

If you have an array, `a` of say 210 rows by 8 columns:

```
a = numpy.empty([210,8])
```

and want to add a ninth column of zeros you can do this:

```
b = numpy.append(a,numpy.zeros([len(a),1]),1)
```

Comment: This generates return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Comment: hmmmm. Just double checked. It works for me (using IDLE - python version 2.7)

Comment: Perhaps it is because, as suggested by @askewchan, you actually have a recarry? I think this would work if you import using `numpy.genfromtxt` or `numpy.loadtxt`?

Comment: If the shape of the column is (X, ) then you have to .reshape(X, 1) to apply append. This is the case after extracting the columns with data[:,1]

Comment: This works for me using python 3.5, but, YES, one must be careful with shapes to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to use **numpy.insert()**.

The Advantage of `np.insert()` over `np.append` is that you can insert the new columns into custom indices.

```
import numpy as np

X = np.arange(20).reshape(10,2)

X = np.insert(X, [0,2], np.random.rand(X.shape[0]*2).reshape(-1,2)*10, axis=1)
'''
```

Comment: What's happening in the reshape part at the end?

Answer (score 1):

[`np.append`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) or [`np.hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) expects the appended column to be the proper shape, that is N x 1. We can use `np.zeros` to create this zeros column (or `np.ones` to create a ones column) and append it to our original matrix (2D array).

```
def append_zeros(x):
    zeros = np.zeros((len(x), 1))  # zeros column as 2D array
    return np.hstack((x, zeros))   # append column
```

Answer (score 0):

I add a new column with ones to a matrix array in this way:

```
Z = append([[1 for _ in range(0,len(Z))]], Z.T,0).T
```

Maybe it is not that efficient?

Comment: Don't use that list comprehension, use [`np.ones`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html) or [`np.ones_like`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ones_like.html):  `append([np.ones_like(Z)], Z.T, 0).T`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this:

```
import numpy as np

# create a random matrix:
A = np.random.normal(size=(5,2))

# add a column of zeros to it:
print(np.hstack((A,np.zeros((A.shape[0],1)))))
```

In general, if A is an m*n matrix, and you need to add a column, you have to create an n*1 matrix of zeros, then use "hstack" to add the matrix of zeros to the right of the matrix A.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to some of the other answers suggesting using `numpy.hstack`, but more readable:

```
import numpy as np

# declare 10 rows x 3 cols integer array of all 1s
arr = np.ones((10, 3), dtype=np.int64)

# get the number of rows in the original array (as if we didn't know it was 10 or it could be different in other cases)
numRows = arr.shape[0]
# declare the new array which will be the new column, integer array of all 0s so it's visually distinct from the original array
additionalColumn = np.zeros((numRows, 1), dtype=np.int64)

# use hstack to tack on the additionl column
result = np.hstack((arr, additionalColumn))

print(result)
```

result:

```
$ python3 scratchpad.py 
[[1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter one-liner:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(210, 8)
data = np.c_[data, np.zeros(len(data))]
```

Something that I use often to convert points to homogenous coordinates with `np.ones` instead.