# Create new column in Python array based on values calculated in the code

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, addition, arcpy

Currently I have an array formatted like this: arr = [(1,1),(1,1)...(35,1),(35,1)])

I've written a code that calculates a 3rd value for each ordered pair in the array, one at a time. How can I create a new column that stores each calculated value as a new column in my array?

Comment: Is `arr` a NumPy array? Or a Python list? In other words, what does `type(arr)` return?

Comment: Duplicate: [How to add column to numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815854/how-to-add-column-to-numpy-array). Take a look at [`numpy.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).

Comment: I already looked at that, but I wasn't sure if it worked with values that were being calculated in my code.

Comment: Just create an array with your calculated values. Then concatenate the two arrays together. Make sure you concatenate using the correct axis.

Answer (score 1):

Tuples are immutable, so you can't directly alter them. Fortunately, you can concatenate another tuple to them. Suppose you have an array:

```
arr = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

and you want to append some integer to each tuple, let's say the index of the tuple in `arr` just for simplicity. That is, you want the final list to be:

```
arr = [(1, 2, 0), (3, 4, 1), (5, 6, 2)]
```

The following code will do just that:

```
arr = [item + (a.index(item),) for item in arr]
```

Note that the comma and parentheses in `(a.index(item),)` are crucial to form a tuple instead of an integer. (You can only concatenate tuples to other tuples.) So if you just want to add a number to a specific tuple, try:

```
arr[0] += (3,)
```

which will append a `3` to the end of the first element in `arr`. That will allow you to perform such concatenation in whatever loop is generating the third point, which you say happens one at a time. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

alternate solution, just replace the tuples as you go.

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    arr[i] = (arr[i][0], arr[i][1], arr[i][0] * arr[i][1])
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array formated as arr = [(1,1),(1,1)...(35,1),(35,1)]` can be confusing.  It looks like an `list` of `tuples`.  If that is what it is then, you need to use a list comprehension to make a new list:

```
arr1 = [(i,j, fun(i,j)) for i,j in arr]
```

e.g.

```
In [359]: arr=[(1,1),(1,2),(35,1),(35,2)]
In [360]: [(i[0],i[1], sum(i)) for i  in arr]
Out[360]: [(1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (35, 1, 36), (35, 2, 37)]
```

But you say in a comment that `arr` is a numpy array.

```
In [361]: Arr=np.array(arr)    
In [362]: Arr
Out[362]: 
array([[ 1,  1],
       [ 1,  2],
       [35,  1],
       [35,  2]])
```

Same numbers, but it displays as a list of lists.  An array that displays as a list of tuples is a structured array, with a different `dtype`.

Is the function something that can take this whole array, or must it be feed the values 2 by 2?

`np.sum` takes the whole array, and can return a 2d result:

```
In [366]: np.sum(Arr, axis=1, keepdims=True)
Out[366]: 
array([[ 2],
       [ 3],
       [36],
       [37]])
```

which can be easily concatenated onto `Arr` giving a new array:

```
In [370]: np.concatenate([Arr,np.sum(Arr, axis=1, keepdims=True)],axis=1)
Out[370]: 
array([[ 1,  1,  2],
       [ 1,  2,  3],
       [35,  1, 36],
       [35,  2, 37]])
```

On the other hand the `Python` `sum` just takes numbers.  `Arr` can be used in a comprehension just like the list:

```
In [371]: [sum(i) for i  in Arr]
Out[371]: [2, 3, 36, 37]
```

To concatenate that onto the original, I need to turn it into a 2d 'vertical' array (as shown in Out[366])

```
In [376]: np.concatenate([Arr,np.array([sum(i) for i in Arr])[:,None]],axis=1)
Out[376]: 
array([[ 1,  1,  2],
       [ 1,  2,  3],
       [35,  1, 36],
       [35,  2, 37]])
```

`append`, `vstack`, `hstack` are all variations on `concatenate`.  You could also construct a `(4,3)` array, and insert the values of `Arr` and new calculation.