# Add a column to numpy 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 60000 by 200 numpy array. I want to make it 60000 by 201 by adding a column of 1's to the right (so every row is `[prev, 1]`).

Concatenate with `axis = 1` doesn't work because it seems like concatenate requires all input arrays to have the same dimension.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Let me just throw in a very simple example with much smaller size. The principle should be the same.

```
a = np.zeros((6,2))
    array([[ 0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.]])
b = np.ones((6,1))
    array([[ 1.],
           [ 1.],
           [ 1.],
           [ 1.],
           [ 1.],
           [ 1.]])

np.hstack((a,b))
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Comment: This works! My array is 60000 by 201 now.  Thanks. the trick here is to define np.ones() as (6, 1) instead of (6,), which is what I've been doing.

Comment: Interestingly if you define `b=np.ones(6)` the procedure won't work. Sometimes Numpy makes me vomit.

Comment: @SanduUrsu You would need to do `b = np.ones((6,1))` for that to work

Comment: @SanduUrsu examine `.shape` for `np.ones(6)` and `np.ones((6,1))`

Answer (score 25):

Using numpy index trick to append a 1D vector to a 2D array

```
a = np.zeros((6,2))
# array([[ 0.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  0.]])
b = np.ones(6) # or np.ones((6,1))
#array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
np.c_[a,b]
# array([[0., 0., 1.],
#        [0., 0., 1.],
#        [0., 0., 1.],
#        [0., 0., 1.],
#        [0., 0., 1.],
#        [0., 0., 1.]])
```

Answer (score 5):

Under cover all the `stack` variants (including `append` and `insert`) end up doing a `concatenate`.  They just precede it with some sort of array reshape.

```
In [60]: A = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)

In [61]: np.concatenate([A, np.ones((A.shape[0],1),dtype=A.dtype)], axis=1)
Out[61]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  1],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  1],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11,  1]])
```

Here I made a (3,1) array of 1s, to match the (3,4) array.  If I wanted to add a new row, I'd make a (1,4) array.

While the variations are handy, if you are learning, you should become familiar with `concatenate` and the various ways of constructing arrays that match in number of dimensions and necessary shapes.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to think about is that `numpy` arrays are really not meant to change size.  So you should ask yourself, can you create your original matrix as 60k x 201 and then fill the last column afterwards.  This is usually best.

If you really must do this, see
[How to add column to numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815854/how-to-add-column-to-numpy-array)

Answer (score 1):

I think the numpy method **column_stack** is more interesting because you do not need to create a column numpy array to stack it in the matrix of interest. With the **column_stack** you just need to create a normal numpy array.

Comment: What does `column_stack` do (under the cover) that is different from `hstack`?

Comment: Does the same, but do do not need to create a column array was you did. You can use a line array and the `column_stack` will stack it as a new column of the matrix you want to be stacked with a new column. With the `hstack` you must use a column array otherwise it will return a error.

Comment: @hpaulj: the first answer just shows an example of column_stack https://stackoverflow.com/a/63144310/3854750. As Randerson mentioned, the second array being added can be either column array of shape (N,1) or just a simple linear array of shape (N,)

Comment: `column_stack` just makes sure the array(s) is 2d, changing the (N,) to (N,1) if necessary.  All these  'stack' functions end up using `np.concatenate`, with varying degrees of frontend tweaking.