# Adding another column to a numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have two arrays of the following dimensions:
a = (6,1) b = (6,4)
I wish to add array (a) as additional column to array (c).

Tried: 
c= np.column_stack([b,a]) 
and get an error due to mismatch of dimensions.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815854/how-to-add-column-to-numpy-array and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486294/how-to-add-an-extra-column-to-an-numpy-array

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
c = np.concatenate((b,a), axis=1)
```

This assumes that `a.shape = (6,1)`. If `a.shape = (6,)` then you can do:

```
c = np.concatenate((b,a.reshape((6,1))), axis=1)
```